# Is there a way to control what gets into a GitHubs zipball?

Tags: github

Every GitHub repo has the `Download ZIP` button, but is there a way to control what gets into the final zipball. For example we do not need and hidden files there, or even - unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Exporting-Your-Repository):

> You can tell Git not to export certain files or directories when
>   generating an archive. If there is a subdirectory or file that you
>   don’t want to include in your archive file but that you do want
>   checked into your project, you can determine those files via the
>   ***export-ignore*** attribute.
>
> For example, say you have some test files in a test/ subdirectory, and
>   it doesn’t make sense to include them in the tarball export of your
>   project. You can add the following line to your Git attributes file:
>
> `test/ export-ignore`
>
> Now, when you run git archive to create a tarball of your project,
>   that directory won’t be included in the archive.

Comment: I would dislike you if I could.